# Replace entered value of textbox in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

In an MS Access DB table, I have decimal field; let's say "Price".  The user should be able to enter any of these options in a text box on the Form:

- If the user enters a decimal value -> it's the product price, so save it in DB
- If the user enters nothing -> this means the value should be saved as NULL
- If the user enters "*" text ->  this means they can't get the price

The problem is with "*", since the field is decimal I can't store an asterisk because it's text, therefore I need to store -1 value instead. I tried to handle that in the Before_Update event of the text box, but it doesn't work.

Who can advise how to implement that?

Comment: Are you sure you want such abnormal thing? Why NULL can't mean can't get price?

Comment: NULL means user entered nothing

Comment: why could user enter nothing in price field?

Comment: because that such client's requirement :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I ALWAYS suggest people not use bound forms. Trying to undo a record in a bound form is always dicey. Unbind the form. That is, have no table as its recordsource. Once all the data is input by the user, have a "Submit" button that will run VBA to write the record to your data. If you do this, you can put anything you want in that Price box, and when you're writing the data to the table you can change it to whatever you want by using an If/Then/Else statement to write the value to that field.

Something sorta like this:

```
Dim DB as database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set DB = CurrentDB
Set rec = DB.OpenRecordset ("Select * from MyTable")

rec.AddNew
rec("MyField") = Me.SomeField
rec("MyField2") = Me.SomeOtherField
if Me.MyPriceField = "*" then
rec("PriceField") = -1
Else
rec("PriceField") = Me.MyPriceField
End If
rec.Update
```

Comment: Not sure why anyone would downvote this answer, it's straight from a textbook.  Haters are gonna hate, I guess.  ;o)

Comment: Isn't it too strange and unusual to write in a way that makes you rewrite most of access's internal procedures? Using of unbound forms triples amount of code you have to write.

Comment: Not if you want it done right.  I've been using Access for 20 years.  This stuff is **TEXTBOOK**.  You can cluge it if you want, like your answer, but this is how it **should** be done.

Comment: What textbook could advice such unnatural approach?

Comment: n00bs would use a bound form.  People who know what they're doing will always use an unbound form.  Much more control, and this problem is a great example of how to properly control user input.

Comment: "this problem is a great example" of bad design only.

Comment: BTW, downvoting answers because they compete with yours or you simply don't understand them is generally frowned upon on SE.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - I didn't downvote as the suggested solution in itself is fine (indeed, I've upvoted because of that). However, a blanket 'no bound controls' policy gives rise to the question of why use Access for the UI in the first place, if you are going to deliberately avoid its core RAD features.

Comment: @ChrisRolliston - Sometimes, for a quick and dirty form, I admit I use it.  But Access is more of an entry level UI app.  When you've developed with it as long as I have (not that I'm proud of it, mind you...) you realize that a lot of that "easy to put together" stuff is just not designed well.  Have you ever tried to put an "Undo" button on a bound form?  It's a mess, it almost never works right.  It's just a fact that if you have a lot of things going on with a form, it's best to leave it unbound so you can control everything better.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - on that particular point, surely it's better to train users 'you can't endlessly undo in Access like in Excel' while introducing them to the Escape key's function.

Comment: "train users"...  ROFL!  When you have apps with 200+ users, there's always a couple knuckleheads in the group.  ALWAYS.  You have to assume they're all knuckleheads and make it as foolproof as possible.  This is where unbound forms become completely necessary. And the Escape key doesn't always work.  Have a look here, where Hans Up (a name you'll recognize from Access questions) suggests a "disconnected recordset".  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662181/is-there-a-way-to-override-automatic-record-updating-of-access-2007-forms-create/3662242#3662242

Answer (score -1):

Try to use OnChange event

```
if nz(Me.CrazyTextBox.Text , "") = "*" then
    Me.CrazyTextBox.Text = -1
end if
```

And think about setting Format string for this crazy text box to something like

```
# ##0.00;\*;0;"user entered nothing"
```

Comment: and may be it is good idea to just add boolean field [can't get the price] instead of making magic

Comment: You should put that as a separate answer, because it looks the best one to me (though maybe call the field PriceUnavailable to avoid potential double 'nots' - Not CannotGetPrice).